# Can we add data into table storage which has same partition key and same row key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage

I need to save `List<period>` into table storage  for client class using batch insert.

```
 class period {
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    }
```

How can we do this?

- I have assigned same partition key and row key (client Id) to each period, is it correct way (query executes but i cant see data into table)?
- shall I create different row key for each object?
- can we store `JSON` string into table storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [PartitionKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/designing-a-scalable-partitioning-strategy-for-azure-table-storage#uyi): The PartitionKey property stores string values that identify the partition that an entity belongs to. Partitions, as we discuss later, are integral to the scalability of the table. **Entities that have the same PartitionKey value are stored in the same partition.**
>
> RowKey: **The RowKey property** stores string values that **uniquely identify entities** within each partition. The PartitionKey and the RowKey together form the primary key for the entity.

So I do not suggest you assign same partition key and row key to each period. You can use same partition key and different row key to uniquely identify entities.

The following table shows the [supported property types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model) for the Table service:

[image]

You can add a json as string in it.

[image]